# Change excel VLOOKUP to index

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a spreadsheet that creates a hyperlink when the VLOOKUP finds a partial match from one column. This one column is called FILE LIST. The FILE LIST contains 20,000 rows. My spreadsheet is slowing down. I was told it would be better if I change from VLOOKUP to INDEX. I'm not familiar with INDEX at all. But how do I do that?

My formula right now is this:

```
=IFERROR(HYPERLINK("\\oes-cityhall\DATA\CITYWIDE\public\fppc filings\2013\" & 
            VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE("*"&B9&"*"),FileName!D:D,1,FALSE),2013),"")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually drop the `CONCATENATE`. It won't change much, but it's an additional processing all the same:

```
=IFERROR(HYPERLINK("\\oes-cityhall\DATA\CITYWIDE\public\fppc filings\2013\" & 
        INDEX(FileName!D:D,MATCH("*"&B9&"*",FileName!D:D,0)),2013),"")
```

Also, if you have the exact number of rows, use that. For instance, if you have 25000 rows, use:

```
=IFERROR(HYPERLINK("\\oes-cityhall\DATA\CITYWIDE\public\fppc filings\2013\" & 
   INDEX(FileName!D$1:D$25000,MATCH("*"&B9&"*",FileName!D$1:D$25000,0)),2013),"")
```

The formula is a little longer, but it will definitely take less time (it will shorten the time whenever there's no match, since as long as it finds no match, it will keep looking into the other cells).

---

To name the hyperlink as the matched result, you'd repeat the `INDEX` formula:

```
=IFERROR(HYPERLINK("\\oes-cityhall\DATA\CITYWIDE\public\fppc filings\2013\" & 
   INDEX(FileName!D$1:D$25000,MATCH("*"&B9&"*",FileName!D$1:D$25000,0)),
   INDEX(FileName!D$1:D$25000,MATCH("*"&B9&"*",FileName!D$1:D$25000,0))),"")
```

If B9 is blank, then:

```
=IFERROR(HYPERLINK("\\oes-cityhall\DATA\CITYWIDE\public\fppc filings\2013\" & 
   INDEX(FileName!D$1:D$25000,IF(B9="",NA(),MATCH("*"&B9&"*",FileName!D$1:D$25000,0))),
   INDEX(FileName!D$1:D$25000,IF(B9="",NA(),MATCH("*"&B9&"*",FileName!D$1:D$25000,0)))),"")
```

Comment: Thank you for your tip. Instead of naming the hyperlink 2013. I want it to be named as the result of the match. How do I do that?

Comment: @user3242868 You mean you want to change all the `2013` in the hyperlink (there are two that I can see) to the matched result? For example, if the matched result is 2014, then the hyperlink would be named 2014?

Comment: Yes that's how I would want it. So what do I put in place of 2013?

Comment: @user3242868 You'll have to repeat the `INDEX`. I'll edit that in my answer since it'll be easier to see there. Or if you can put `=INDEX(FileName!D$1:D$25000,MATCH("*"&B9&"*",FileName!D$1:D$25000,0))` in a separate cell, say, E9, then you just need to put `E9` instead: `=IFERROR(HYPERLINK("\\oes-cityhall\DATA\CITYWIDE\public\fppc filings\2013\" & E9, E9), "")`

Comment: That worked out great. One more question, what do I put if B9 is blank? At the moment, it is returning a value when it's supposed to remain blank.

Comment: @user3242868 Hmm, I'm a bit surprised that you have such a situation. I guess you have some blank cells in the middle of column B. You could perhaps wrap the whole MATCH part into an if: `IF(B9="",NA(),MATCH("*"&B9&"*",FileName!D$1:D$25000,0))`. That should  make the function end early if B9 is blank and then return blank.

Answer (score 1):

replace your vlookup with something like this:

```
INDEX(Filename!E:E,MATCH(CONCATENATE("*"&B9&"*"),FileName!D:D,0))
```

*EDIT*

My mistake.  I misread the 1 as a 2 in the vlookup.

This should work:

```
INDEX(Filename!D:D,MATCH(CONCATENATE("*"&B9&"*"),FileName!D:D,0))
```

Comment: My Column E is empty.

Comment: I misread what you were looking to return.  I thought you wanted the value from the next column.  
Change the Filename!E:E to Filename!D:D